# Custom Cygwin distribution?

Tags: cygwin

Is there anyway to create a Cygwin distribution that has customized packages? In other words, can I just zip up my cygwin folder and unzip it to another computer for it to work straight away?

Or are there registry\path configurations that would only bet set correctly by running the setup.exe?

Comment: Don't know, but why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: There are many computers in my network that require the same Cygwin setup with the same plug-in's, etc.  So if I could create a single distribution, I could just copy it to each computer and don't have to download the plug-in's individually again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd browse the [Cygwin Archives](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/) to answer this question.

(added after Bei337's first comment)

I believe the [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq.html) answers your question.

Comment: Can't seem to find the answer...maybe I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: @Bei337: See section 2.2 of the Cygwin FAG. It indicates how you can perform an automated cygwin installation.

Comment: Section 2.2 of the Cygwin FAQ mentions "saving the entire downloaded package tree".  Where is the "downloaded package tree" located?

Comment: I found it, it's the "cygwininstall" folder on the same level as the "cygwin" folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive (e.g. zip, 7-zip etc.) the contents of the cygwin directory and it'll work on another computer after unarchiving if you make sure that cygwin.bat contains the correct paths.